# Почему программа завершается с этого момента: Student student(sname, age, mark, course, student_number);group.setStudent(student, student_number);?

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "interface.h"
#include "Group.h"
#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    char answer = 'y';
    cout << "\tWELCOME to group manager! Copyrights M.B.(c)\n";
    int action;
    string group_name;
    int quantity;
    int counter = 0;
    Group group;

    while (answer = 'y')
    {
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            cout << "Enter the name of group: ";
            cin >> group_name;
            cout << "Enter the quantity of students in this group: ";
            cin >> quantity;

            if (!cin)
            {
                cout << "\nWrong number!\n";
                break;
            }

            Group group1(group_name, quantity);
            group = group1;
        }

        cout << "Choose the action: \n\t1 - Show all group\n\t2 - Add student\n\t3 - Show info about student(after creating)\n";
        cin >> action;

        if (!cin)
        {
            cout << "\nWrong number!\n";
            break;
        }

        string sname;

        switch (action)
        {
            case 1:
                group.showAllInfo();
                break;

            case 2:
            {
                cout << "\nEnter student number: ";
                int student_number;
                cin >> student_number;

                if (!cin)
                {
                    cout << "\nWrong number!\n";
                    break;
                }

                cout << "\nStudent's name:";
                cin >> sname;
                cout << "\nStudent's age:";
                int age;
                cin >> age;

                if (!cin)
                {
                    cout << "\nWrong number!\n";
                    break;
                }

                cout << "\nStudent's average mark:";
                float mark;
                cin >> mark;

                if (!cin)
                {
                    cout << "\nWrong number!\n";
                    break;
                }

                cout << "\nStudent's course:";
                int course;
                cin >> course;

                if (!cin)
                {
                    cout << "\nWrong number!\n";
                    break;
                }

                Student student(sname, age, mark, course, student_number);
                group.setStudent(student, student_number);
            }
            break;

            case 3:
                int num;
                cout << "Enter the number of student";
                cin >> num;

                if (!cin)
                {
                    cout << "\nWrong number!\n";
                    break;
                }

                group.showThisStudent(num);
                break;

            default:
                cout << "Wrong number";
                break;
        }

        counter++;
        cout << "Go on?y/n\n";
        cin >> answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в код классы `Group`, `Student`

Comment: Начнем с того, что в `while (answer = 'y')` вы вряд ли хотели именно присваивание, а не сравнение... Ну, а дальше - завершается как? С ошибкой? С какой-то диагностикой? Чего вы от нее ждете? Словом, прочтите для начала, [как правильно задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...